Detailed balance in the one-dimensional Fokker-Planck equation
Consider a 1-dimensional SDE given by
$$
dx_t = f(x_t) + \sigma(x_t)dW_t.
$$
If the process is stationary then its density satisfies the Fokker-Planck equation with $\partial p(x,t)/ \partial t = 0$ i.e.
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(fp-\frac{d}{dx}(Dp))=0.
$$
Where $D=\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(x)$.
It makes sense that because the stationary process in 1d then its probability flux,
$$
J= fp -\frac{d}{dx}(Dp)=0
$$
meaning that the process is in detailed balance and is reversible. However, I cannot seem to derive this. The stationarity condition only guarantees that $J=c$ i.e. that the stationary flux is constant in space. I do not know how to show that this must be zero.
From a purely physical argument, one can say that the flux in and out of a region must be 0, therefore it cannot be a non-zero constant, but this does not seem to come out the equations. Am I missing some zero-flux at the infinite boundary condition? How would I show that all these 1-dimensional diffusions are in fact reversible?

Indeed, this fact is usually deduced from initial/boundary conditions. Nevertheless, the stationary flux may be a non-zero constant, for example with a periodic boundary condition, where a particle can disappear on the right and reappear on the left for instance $-$ it would mean that the particle moves on a circle.

If that is not the case, i.e. you just have the particle moving along the infinite line, how would I make rigourous my point, that this must be reversible?

Then, you can impose a zero-flux condition at infinity, as you expected.
